# When .aws directory is created on linux box:

Tags: amazon-web-services

when we install awscli on linux box ?
Installation Amazon Command line interface tool to interact with AWS Services:
AWS Cli is used to access resources like EC2, S3 Bucket and other aws services:

This command is for  Linux batch

installed awscli
apt install awscli

Answer (score 1):

The `~/.aws` directory is created when you run the `aws configure` command to store your credentials.

For example:

```bash
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

See: [Configuration and credential file settings - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-methods)

Answer (score -1):

The ~/.aws directory is created when you run the aws configure command.

.aws directory has two files

config and
credentials

Install awscli and configure awscli , then it will create .aws directory.
.aws directory has two files
config and
credentails.

1).Install AWS CLI
commands:

```
             apt update -y
             apt install awscli -y
```

Check version:

```
           aws --v
           aws-cli/1.22.34 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.19.0-1025-aws 
           botocore/1.23.34
```

2. Configure aws cli: provide access key and secret key
   Check .aws directory :

   ```
        root@ip-xxxxxxxxxxx:~# aws configure
        AWS Access Key ID [None]: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        AWS Secret Access Key [None]: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        Default region name [None]:
        Default output format [None]:
   ```

3). Check .aws directory (aws is a hidden directory start with .)

```
           root@ip-172-31-15-200:~# ls -alrt
           total 28
           -rw-r--r--  1 root root  161 Jul  9  2019 .profile
           -rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Oct 15  2021 .bashrc
           drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Oct 18 06:45 ..
           drwx------  2 root root 4096 Oct 18 06:45 .ssh
           drwx------  4 root root 4096 Oct 18 06:45 snap
           drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 18 06:54 .aws
           drwx------  5 root root 4096 Oct 18 06:54 .
```

Comment: The ~/.aws directory is created  to store your credentials.